# $R$ an integral domain and $S\subset R$, prove that $F(R)=F(S) \implies R=S$?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $S$ be a unital subring of $R$.

If the two field of fractions $F(R)=F(S)$, does it imply that $R=S$.

Im pretty sure it does, but can't think of a proof.

Comment: $F(\Bbb Z[1/a]) = F(\Bbb Z).\,$ Generally if $\, S \subseteq R\subseteq F(S)\,$ then $\,F(R) = F(S).\ \ $

Comment: Sorry i meant to say unital subring. @EricTowers

Comment: Deleting your question is disrespecting those who helped out your question, rendering the answers meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement you wrote down is false. Here is a counterexample:

$\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ have the same fraction field, i.e.

$$F(\mathbb{Z})= F(\mathbb{Q})= \mathbb{Q}$$

but $\mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Counterexample*:

Consider any element $f\in\mathbf Z$, $f\ne 0,1,-1$. Then $\;\mathbf Z\varsubsetneq \mathbf Z_f$, yet $\mathbf Q$ is their common  field of fractions.